# How to get data back from BroadcastReceiver to Activity?

Tags: android

I wrote sms application for which I wrote BroadcastReceiver. I want to get data from BroadcastReceiver into my activity, so how do I get it.

My Broadcast Receiver code is below:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
         //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str +=  msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     

            }

            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }       
    }
}
```

I want to get back "str" value into another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sms-text", str);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

---

in your activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String sms = intent.getExtras().getString("sms-text");
```

Comment: Does this work even if MyActivity is running? Will it cause onCreate to rerun or anything like that?