# Can't get back data from Broadcast Reciever

Tags: android

HI ,
I refered and add the code into BroadcastReceiver and activity ,which is given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699818/how-to-get-data-back-from-broadcastreciever-to-activity).

**But still  I am having problem in getting phone number from my broadcast receiver into another activity log cat shows error at line**

```
String  sms = intent.getExtras().getString("sms-text");
```

Plese give me right solution .help me.

Comment: hi vladimir ,actually i want to do app which sends automatic sms to the sender when user gets sms.but i cant do it becasue of above line

Comment: what error do you have in the logcat? Post the stacktrace, please.

Comment: you need to give more detail... 1) what is the entire line of the error. 2) show all code creating the intent broadcast 3) show all code for init of broadcast recevier 4) what are all the links of the broadcast receiver not just the 1 line you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're starting the activity not only from broadcast receiver, but manually two. In that case there is no extra in the intent. Just add the null reference check:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String sms = "";
if (bundle != null) {
  sms = bundle.getString("sms-text");
}
```